# Validations signup fields weird issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm stuck with (I guess) a JavaScript syntax problem.

I'm building a React signUp form. I created these functions for validating the input data. It's supposed to return an error message in the form fields if some inputs are wrong, and it's working fine if only one calls the `onChange()` function, but when i try to call both, it only works with the last one, I can't understand why.

Each component looks like this:

```
<InputField error={error.email === '' ? false : true} helperText={error.email} />

const handleChange = input => event => {
  verifyUser();
  verifyPass();
};

const verifyUser = () => {
  if (loginValues.email !== '') {
    if (checkEmailFormat()) {
      if (!checkEmailRegistered()) {
        setUserVerified({ ...userVerified, email: true });
        setError({ ...error, email: '' });
      } else {
        setError({ ...error, email: 'Email already registered' });
      }
    } else {
      setError({ ...error, email: 'Enter a valid email adress' });
    }
  } else {
    setError({ ...error, email: 'Email field empty' });
  }
};

const verifyPass = () => {
  if (loginValues.pass !== '' && loginValues.rptpass !== '') {
    if (checkPassMatch()) {
      setUserVerified({ ...userVerified, pass: true });
      setError({ ...error, pass: '', rptpass: '' });
    } else {
      setError({
        ...error,
        pass: 'Passwords does not match',
        rptpass: 'Passwords does not match',
      });
    }
  } else if (loginValues.pass === '') {
    setError({ ...error, pass: 'Password field empty' });
  } else if (loginValues.rptpass === '') {
    setError({ ...error, rptpass: 'Password field empty' });
  }
};
```

I have tried to convert to promise each function and then, call from onChange like this:

```
verifyUser().then(()=>{verifyPass()}
```

or with callBacks, but with the same result. It only works the last one function.

Comment: when is handleChange invoked and how ?

Comment: We're missing a lot of the functions being called like `checkEmailFormat` and `checkEmailRegistered`. You're capturing the event in the `handleChange` function, but I don't see it used. Is it? Can you build a codesandbox to show us a minimum reproduction environment?